How to implement opening a modal window with a table on double-clicking a canvas metricValue element?
I have a task to extend the functionality of the canvas. Specifically, I need to add the ability to open a modal window upon selecting a value for matricValue and double-clicking on an element, where the data would be displayed in a table. What would be the best way to implement this?

